# Colour a cell based on another cell being blank AND another cell being filled

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors, conditional-formatting

I have a question concerning conditional formatting in excel:
I want to highlight one cell (lets say F1) in red but only if F6 it self is empty/blank and B1 is filled (it doesn't matter with what): How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
=AND(ISBLANK(F6),NOT(ISBLANK(B1)))
```

or

```
=AND(F6="",B1<>"")
```

in conditional formatting.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select cell F1
2. Open Conditional Formatting
3. Select "New rule" then "Use a formula"
4. Use a formula that results in TRUE or FALSE
5. In your case use =AND(ISBLANK(F6);NOT(ISBLANK(B1)))